# Error installing Theano for GPU 750m in Canopy on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, cuda, canopy, theano

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit. I have installed canopy with academic license. My laptop has Nvidia GeForce GT750m

I have installed Theano using `python setup.py develop` from Theano's git repository. I have Visual Studio 2013 and Cuda Toolkit 64 bit installed. Cuda samples are working fine.

Theanoarc file:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
```

I get the following error while doing `import theano`

```
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\include\pymath.h(22): warning: dllexport/dllimport conflict with "round"

c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v6.5\include\math_functions.h(2455): here; dllimport/dllexport dropped



mod.cu(672): warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer



mod.cu(954): warning: statement is unreachable



mod.cu(1114): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1145): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1173): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1174): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1317): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1318): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1442): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1443): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1742): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1777): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1781): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1814): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1821): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1853): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1861): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1898): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1905): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1946): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(1960): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(2684): warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer



mod.cu(3750): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3752): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3784): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3786): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3789): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3791): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3794): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3795): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3836): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(3838): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(4602): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



mod.cu(4604): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"



31 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/Harsh/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00001e58_00000000-10_mod.cpp1.ii".

mod.cu


['nvcc', '-shared', '-g', '-O3', '--compiler-bindir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=d67f7c8a21306c67152a70a88a837011,/Zi,/MD', '-IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\\include', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.6-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\libs', '-LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\\libs', '-LNone\\lib', '-LNone\\lib64', '-LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64', '-lpython27', '-lcublas', '-lcudart']
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 2, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -g -O3 --compiler-bindir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin -Xlinker /DEBUG -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=d67f7c8a21306c67152a70a88a837011,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\\include -o C:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.6-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\libs -LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\\libs -LNone\\lib -LNone\\lib64 -LC:\\Users\\Harsh\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64 -lpython27 -lcublas -lcudart')
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available
```

VisualStudio Command prompt gives the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>cd C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\
pycuda-2012.1

C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\pycuda-2012.1>set VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%

C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\pycuda-2012.1>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_driver' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/cpp/cuda.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/cpp/cuda.obj
cuda.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
c:\users\harsh\downloads\pycuda-2012.1\src\cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: u
nary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/cpp/bitlog.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/cpp/bitlog.obj
bitlog.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/wrapper/wrap_cudadrv.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/
wrap_cudadrv.obj
wrap_cudadrv.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
src/cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned
 type, result still unsigned
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\
include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy
 API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/wrapper/mempool.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/mempo
ol.obj
mempool.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
src/cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned
 type, result still unsigned
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\
include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy
 API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
c:\users\harsh\downloads\pycuda-2012.1\src\wrapper\mempool.cpp(256) : fatal erro
r C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 228)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the l
ocations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
VC\BIN\cl.exe'
    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.e
xe"' failed with exit status 1

C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\pycuda-2012.1>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to pycuda.egg-info\requires.txt
writing pycuda.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pycuda.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pycuda.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pycuda.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.cpp' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
boost'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset
\boost'
warning: no files found matching '*.inl' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
boost'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
boost'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\li
bs'
warning: no files found matching '*.hpp' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
libs'
warning: no files found matching '*.ipp' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
libs'
warning: no files found matching '*.pl' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\l
ibs'
writing manifest file 'pycuda.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_driver' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/cpp/cuda.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/cpp/cuda.obj
cuda.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
c:\users\harsh\downloads\pycuda-2012.1\src\cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: u
nary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/cpp/bitlog.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/cpp/bitlog.obj
bitlog.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/wrapper/wrap_cudadrv.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/
wrap_cudadrv.obj
wrap_cudadrv.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
src/cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned
 type, result still unsigned
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\
include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy
 API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOU
RCE=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREA
D_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bp
l_subset "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -Ic
:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\i
nclude -IC:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.
1975.win-x86_64\include -Ic:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\PC
/Tpsrc/wrapper/mempool.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/mempo
ol.obj
mempool.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\app\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-
x86_64\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(51
6) : see previous definition of 'round'
src/cpp\cuda.hpp(1786) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned
 type, result still unsigned
c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\
include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy
 API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
c:\users\harsh\downloads\pycuda-2012.1\src\wrapper\mempool.cpp(256) : fatal erro
r C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 228)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the l
ocations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
VC\BIN\cl.exe'
    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.e
xe"' failed with exit status 1
```

`INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
VC\BIN\cl.exe'`  in the last line

I have followed [Installing theano on Windows 8 with GPU enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729969/installing-theano-on-windows-8-with-gpu-enabled)

But **Python distutils fix** cannot be applied as I have used Canopy. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Theano do not support Visual Studio compiler. It is needed for cuda, but not for Theano CPU code. This need g++ compiler.

Is the canopy package for the compiler correctly installed? What did you do to try to compile with microsoft compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Canopy, like all standard CPython 2.7 distributions for Windows, is compiled with Visual C++ 2008, and that is the compiler that you should use for compiling all non-trivial C extensions for it.

The following article includes some links for obtaining this compiler:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/26864394-Windows-Unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-cython-f2py-other-c-extensions-