# Theano with Anaconda on Windows: how to setup BLAS?

Tags: python, windows, theano, keras, blas

I've used Anaconda to install Theano (and Keras) on Windows 7 64bit.
Here are my steps.

1. Install the latest Anaconda for Python 3.5
2. conda install mingw libpython
3. pip install Theano
4. conda install pydot-ng
5. pip install keras
6. Edit .keras/keras.json to use "theano" instead of "tensorflow".

Open Jupyter, copy and paste this code: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py
It executes fine until the call to model.fit : imports, data download, model compilation all work.

Please note that I set data_augmentation to False.

The call to model.fit fails with the following error message:http://pastebin.com/Rq7HTc4H

This seems to be the problem:

> AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no
>   implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you
>   exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU,
>   is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have
>   a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?

I didn't install BLAS myself, I thought that would be a part of Anaconda.
Browsing the internet reveals similar problems.
Apparently you can prevent Theano from looking for a BLAS library by editing a .theanorc.txt file and adding "optimizer = None": [How configure theano on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011551/how-configure-theano-on-windows)

I executed `os.path.expanduser('~/.theanorc.txt')`, verified that my .theanorc.txt is in the right place, added the optimier=None line and tried the code again.
No effect.

How can I configure Theano to work without BLAS ?
Or, even better, how can I install a BLAS library (preferably via Anaconda) ?

**UPDATE:**
Apparently you can edit the config during runtime:

```
import theano
theano.config.optimizer="None"
```

removes the problem.

This means that Theano doesn't find my config file.
I thought I had put it at the correct location, what might prevent Theano from finding it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install theano in Anaconda ver. 2.1 Windows 64 bit for Python 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629347/how-do-i-install-theano-in-anaconda-ver-2-1-windows-64-bit-for-python-3-4)

Answer (score 1):

it should be `os.path.expanduser('~/.theanorc')` without the txt.

use enviroment variable to change theano parameters:
beginning on your code use this to config theano:

```
import os
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'optimizer=None'
```

also you can try this:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/troubleshooting.html#test-blas