# import theano (0.6) on Windows 8 with device= gpu (and visual studios 12.0)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, installation, theano

I'm having an compilation issue when I try to use Theano with the GPU device (it works fine with the CPU). I'm getting almost exactly the same problem to that already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729969/installing-theano-on-windows-8-with-gpu-enabled), however following the solution provided does not work for me. Following the original solution, I can get as far as verifying that pycuda has been installed successfully, but importing theano still throws the same error:

```
c:\python\python27\include\pymath.h(22): warning: dllexport/dllimport conflict with "round"
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v6.5\include\math_functions.h(2455): here; dllimport/dllexport dropped

mod.cu(954): warning: statement is unreachable
mod.cu(1114): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"

... *lots more of the same error at different lines* ...

mod.cu(4604): error: namespace "std" has no member "min"

31 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/Zehan/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_0000317c_00000000-10_mod.cpp1.ii".
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 2, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -g -O3 --compiler-bindir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin -Xlinker /DEBUG -m32 -Xcompiler -LC:\\Python\\Python27\\libs,-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=d67f7c8a21306c67152a70a88a837011,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\Python\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\Python\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\Python\\Python27\\include -o C:\\Users\\Zehan\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\Python\\Python27\\libs -LNone\\lib -LNone\\lib64 -LC:\\Python\\Python27 -lpython27 -lcublas -lcudart')
```

I have Python 2.7.8 32bit and MinGW set up and CUDA 6.5. I'm using the following .theanorc config:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
```

In order to get the pycuda example to work, I had to add visual studio 12.0 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` to my user path. It doesn't work with visual studios 10.0 for some reason, despite using the visual studio 10 command prompt to build pycuda.

Incidentally, if I try `compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin`, I get an error saying that version of visual studio is no good:

```
nvcc fatal: nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2010, 2012, and 2013 are supported
```

(I have visual studio express 2010 and 2013 installed)

I understand that the Theano+GPU support for Windows is still somewhat experimental, but it seems like it does work for some people. Any suggestions as to what try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bit of hack to fix it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/theano-users/warning$20C4273$3A$20$27round$27$20$3A$20inconsistent$20dll$20linkage/theano-users/C8ce20uE6Gs/9Xg7UHazoWAJ)

Essentially it entails finding the `cuda_ndarray.cuh` file in the `<install-dir>/andbox\cuda` and adding `#include <algorithm>`.

It still leaves a warning `warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage`.

Which according to [this reported issue](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2055) is due to a conflict between Python and CUDA and both providing an `round` functionality. This could perhaps be fixed by defining the macro HAVE_ROUND when linking with CUDA to tell Python not to try to redefine round.

Not sure if this is a general fix that's applicable for everyone, but seemed to have worked for me - as far as enabling me to use the GPU with theano.