# CUDA and Theano install Windows 7: Is Visual Studio required?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, theano

I'm in the process of installing Theano and combining it with CUDA on my Windows 7 PC. All the information/tutorials I've seen require Visual Studio to be installed. Most of the Visual Studio versions are >= 5GB in size which seems like a ridiculous number especially for an IDE. Is Visual Studio required to run/compile CUDA code, or can I install an alternative IDE? If it is required, what's the smallest (in size) Visual Studio version?

Comment: *size of Windows 7 is ridiculously huge too*

Comment: @Raptor, you're right. Looking to dual boot my PC soon. AMostMajestuousCapybara, I was dreading this answer. Would you happen to know which version is the smallest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio is explicitly required to run some of the CUDA tools. As of February 2015, your best bet is to download VS 2013 Community Edition (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) and CUDA 6.5 (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073714/2771315) is a great guide for installing CUDA on Windows 7 and 8.