# How to specify a windows directory that has spaces in it in .theanorc

Tags: windows, theano

I need to use the `--compiler-bindir` flag to specify directory that contains `cl.exe` to `nvcc`. If I specify it like this:

```
[nvcc]
flags = --compiler-bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin
```

I get error while importing theano in python that complains about spaces. What is the proper way to specify this directory in `.theanorc`? Note that I do not want to edit my `nvcc.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, if you haven't yet, it seems to work for other people:

```
[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073714) long Stackoverflow guide about installing Theano on Windows.